# Rescale SVG inside an object

Tags: javascript, svg, sass

I try to resize my SVG inside an object in HTML, I tried to put 'reserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"' inside the svg file and I also tried to put object-fit:contain inside the #svg or the #svg-content.

The goal is to get the current X and Y of the circle when I click on it to display a popup next to it, but for now, if I click on a circle then I resize the window, the popup just stay still and don't move because the circle's coordinates didn't change

Here's my scss file :

```
#svg {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;

  &-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Here's my index :

```
 <div id="svg">
        <object
          data="./assets/images/test.svg"
          type="image/svg+xml"
          id="svg-content"
        ></object>
      </div>
```

And my svg :

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="1000" width="1000">
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="40" fill="red"
        data-type="?" />
    <circle cx="400" cy="600" r="40" fill="blue" data-type="i" />
    <rect x="300" y="0" width="10" height="1000" fill="green" id="fake-rect" />
</svg>
```

And my event.js :

```
 circle.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        const circleType = circle.dataset.type;
        if (circleType === "i") {
          console.log(circle.cx.baseVal.value, circle.cy.baseVal.value)
          showPopup(circle.cx.baseVal.value, circle.cy.baseVal.value);
        }
      });
```

EDIT : I made a codepen if you want to copy the files, you just need to add the svg in a separate file [codepen](https://codepen.io/AlpePopas/pen/gOZzOoB)

Regards,

Comment: You probably want CTM conversion: see: https://dev.to/netsi1964/screen-coordinates-to-svg-coordinates-3k0l

Comment: SVG is case sensitive so it's viewBox and not viewbox